# How to read the man page for git revert?

Tags: git, man

When I do a `man git revert`, I get the man page for git:

```
NAME
       git - the stupid content tracker

SYNOPSIS
       git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c <name>=<value>]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]

DESCRIPTION
       Git is a fast, scalable, distributed revision control system with an
       unusually rich command set that provides both high-level operations and
       full access to internals.
...
```

`revert` is the `<command>` listed above. When I try just `man revert`, I get:

```
$ man revert
No manual entry for revert
```

How can I read the man page for `git revert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git has its own help system, invoked via `git help <command>`, as per the usage notes:

```
'git help -a' and 'git help -g' lists available subcommands and some
concept guides. See 'git help <command>' or 'git help <concept>'
to read about a specific subcommand or concept.
```

So, to get info on `git revert` usage

```
$ git help revert
GIT-REVERT(1)                                  Git Manual                                 GIT-REVERT(1)

NAME
     git-revert - Revert some existing commits
```

etc. You may also be interested in the [git scm documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc), which I found very helpful when getting to grips with `git`; and still refer to.

Comment: Ah, `git-revert` is the name of the man page...

Answer (score 0):

That's funny; when I say `man git revert`, it displays [`git-revert(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-revert). 
But anyway,
if you scroll down about 20% of the way into [`git(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git), you'll see

> ### Git Commands
>
> ⋮

followed by

> [git-revert](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-revert)(1)
>
>   Revert an existing commit.

So that's how you learn to say `man git-revert`.